# Get row and column index of value in Pandas df

Tags: pandas

Currently I'm trying to automate scheduling.
I'll get requirement as a .csv file.
However, the number of day changes by month, and personnel also changes occasionally, which means the number of columns and rows is not fixed.

So, I want to put value '*' as a marker meaning end of a table. Unfortunately, I can't find a function or method that take a value as a parameter and return a(list of) index(name of column and row or index numbers).

Is there any way that I can find a(or a list of) index of a certain value?(like coordinate)

for example, when the data frame is like below,

```
  |column_1 |column_2
------------------------
1 | 'a'     | 'b'
------------------------       
2 | 'c'     | 'd'
```

how can I get 'column_2' and '2' by the value, 'd'? It's something similar to the opposite of .loc or .iloc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question. I also used a list comprehension, but with `np.where`. Still I'd be surprised if there isn't a less clunky way.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1':['a','c'], 'column_2':['b','d']}, index=[1,2])

[(i, np.where(df[i] == 'd')[0].tolist()) for i in list(df) if len(np.where(df[i] == 'd')[0]) > 0]

> [[('column_2', [1])]
```

Note that it returns the numeric (0-based) index, not the custom (1-based)  index you have. If you have a fixed offset you could just add a `+1` or whatever to the output.

Answer (score 3):

I might be misunderstanding something, but np.where should get the job done.

```
df_tmp = pd.DataFrame({'column_1':['a','c'], 'column_2':['b','d']}, index=[1,2])

solution = np.where(df_tmp == 'd')
```

solution should contain row and column index.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are looking for: Find the (index value, column location) for a value in a dataframe. You can use list comprehension in a loop. Probably wont be the fastest if your dataframe is large.

```
# assume this dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['abc', 'def','wert','abc'], 'col2':['asdf', 'abc', 'sdfg', 'def']})

# list comprehension

[(df[col][df[col].eq('abc')].index[i], df.columns.get_loc(col)) for col in df.columns for i in range(len(df[col][df[col].eq('abc')].index))]

# [(0, 0), (3, 0), (1, 1)]
```

change `df.columns.get_loc` to `col` if you want the column value rather than location:

```
[(df[col][df[col].eq('abc')].index[i], col) for col in df.columns for i in range(len(df[col][df[col].eq('abc')].index))]

# [(0, 'col'), (3, 'col'), (1, 'col2')]
```

Answer (score 0):

To search single value:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1':['a','c'], 'column_2':['b','d']}, index=[1,2])

df[df == 'd'].stack().index.tolist()

[Out]:
[('column_2', 2)]
```

To search a list of values:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1':['a','c'], 'column_2':['b','d']}, index=[1,2])

df[df.isin(['a', 'd'])].stack().index.tolist()

[Out]:
[(1, 'column_1'), (2, 'column_2')]
```

Also works when value occurs at multiple places:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1':['test','test'], 'column_2':['test','test']}, index=[1,2])

df[df == 'test'].stack().index.tolist()

[Out]:
[(1, 'column_1'), (1, 'column_2'), (2, 'column_1'), (2, 'column_2')]
```

**Explanation**

Select cells where the condition matches:

```py
df[df.isin(['a', 'b', 'd'])]

[Out]:
  column_1 column_2
1        a        b
2      NaN        d
```

[stack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) reshapes the columns to index:

```py
df[df.isin(['a', 'b', 'd'])].stack()

[Out]:
1  column_1    a
   column_2    b
2  column_2    d
```

Now the dataframe is a multi-index:

```py
df[df.isin(['a', 'b', 'd'])].stack().index

[Out]:
MultiIndex([(1, 'column_1'),
            (1, 'column_2'),
            (2, 'column_2')],
           )
```

Convert this multi-index to list:

```py
df[df.isin(['a', 'b', 'd'])].stack().index.tolist()

[Out]:
[(1, 'column_1'), (1, 'column_2'), (2, 'column_2')]
```

**Note**

If a list of values are searched, the returned result does not preserve the order of input values:

```py
df[df.isin(['d', 'b', 'a'])].stack().index.tolist()

[Out]:
[(1, 'column_1'), (1, 'column_2'), (2, 'column_2')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar need and this worked perfectly

```
# deals with case sensitivity concern
df = raw_df.applymap(lambda s: s.upper() if isinstance(s, str) else s)

# get the row index
value_row_location = df.isin(['VALUE']).any(axis=1).tolist().index(True)

# get the column index
value_column_location = df.isin(['VALUE']).any(axis=0).tolist().index(True)

# Do whatever you want to do e.g Replace the value above that cell
df.iloc[value_row_location - 1, value_column_location] = 'VALUE COLUMN'
```