# How to get row and column name by value?

Tags: python, pandas

How to find the column name and row index from dataframe

```
Rn G1 G2 G3 G4
G1 x  a  c  a
G2 a  x  c  a
G3 c  c  x  c
G4 a  a  c  x
```

Above table is my dataframe, how to find the row and column name whose value is 'c'

Output:
`G1 G3`
`G2 G3`
`G3 G4`

I want only unique ones

Comment: How to remove the duplicate get only G1 G3, G2 G3, G3 G4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking credit from @Chris's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54888137/get-row-and-column-index-of-value-in-pandas-df)

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Rn':['G1','G2','G3','G4'],'G1':['x','a','c','a'],'G2':['a','x','c','a'],'G3':['c','c','x','c'],'G4':['a','a','c','x']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('Rn')
locations = [(df[col][df[col].eq('c')].index[i], col) for col in df.columns for i in range(len(df[col][df[col].eq('c')].index))]
print(locations)
```

Output:

```
[('G3', 'G1'), ('G3', 'G2'), ('G1', 'G3'), ('G2', 'G3'), ('G4', 'G3'), ('G3', 'G4')]
```

Where the first value in the tuple is name of the column and the second one the name of the index.

Comment: How to remove duplicates

Comment: There are no duplicates.

Comment: G3 G1 is same as G1 G3  how to remove one either G3 G1 or G1 G3.  Final output should be like [(G3 G1) ,( G3 G2) ,( G4 G3) ]

Comment: No, one is the x coordinate and the other is the y coordinate. A point at (3,1) is definitely not the same as a point in (1,3). You have 6 `c` therefore you should have 6 values in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for column, value in row.iteritems():
    if value == c:
       return index, column // or alternatively store it in a list here
```

There may be a more efficient way, but I am not sure what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

If you dataframe looks like:

```
   G1 G2 G3 G4
Rn            
G1  x  a  c  a
G2  a  x  c  a
G3  c  c  x  c
G4  a  a  c  x
```

Then:

```
v = df.apply(lambda x: [(x.name, c) for c, v in zip(df.columns, x) if v == 'c'], axis=1).explode().tolist()

print(v)
```

Prints:

```
[('G1', 'G3'), ('G2', 'G3'), ('G3', 'G1'), ('G3', 'G2'), ('G3', 'G4'), ('G4', 'G3')]
```