# How can I get the values satisfying some conditions in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I read excel data as dataframe of pandas in which each row has two non-NaN values(others are all NaN)

| names | Unnamed:1 | Unnamed:2 | Unnamed:3 | ~ | Unnamed:19 | Unnamed:20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | NaN | 1.3 | NaN | ~(NaN) | 10.4 | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | NaN | 2.7 | ~(NaN) | NaN | 12.7 |
| ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ |
| name_***ccdd*** | NaN | ***1.3*** | NaN | ~(NaN) | ***9.3*** | NaN |
| ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ |
| name_yyzz | 0.5 | NaN | NaN | ~4.7~ | NaN | NaN |

I'd like to find a specific row containing a word(e.g. "ccdd") and get non-NaN values (e.g. 1.3 and 9.3) in a general way

I made a boolin which contains showing which row index contains a word(e.g. "ccdd")

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

filename= '~/data.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(filename, engine='openpyxl')
mask = df[df.columns[0]].str.contains('ccdd')

print(mask)

0       NaN
1       NaN
2     False
3     False
4     False
5      True
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
13    False
```

the 5th row contains data on what I want to get two float values. but I can't go further.

In a previous article([Get row and column index of the value in Pandas df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54888137/get-row-and-column-index-of-value-in-pandas-df)) I found a similar answer but I don't know how to utilize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass na parameter in `str.contains()` so basically the na parameter set NaN values to True/False according to your input:

```
mask = df[df.columns[0]].str.contains('ccdd',na=False)
```

Now finally pass that mask to your df:

```
df[mask]
#OR
df.loc[mask]
```

Comment: Really thank you for your answer.
If if did df[mask] or df.loc[mask] then I get similar output but without NaN in 0 & 1 row. 
Ultimately I'd like to get the float value of 1.3, 9.3 in 'ccdd' row. 
How can I get the values?

Comment: My fault. 
I could get the row values from your reply, especially `na=False` option.
It really helped me a lot!!

Comment: @dave since if you want to include NaN's then set `na=True` it will include NaN as well and you will get 1.3 and 9.3 in other rows....btw glad this solution helped....happy coding **:)**

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the proper row index:

```
mask=df['names'].str.contains('ccdd')
mask=mask.replace(np.nan, False, regex=True)
list(df.names.index[mask])
```

**Output:**

```
[3]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
But I couldn't apply the `names` method for the `df` dataframe. 
I got the message `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'names'`
and what is `m` in the last code? Is that `mask`?

Comment: That `m` is a typo meant to be `mask`. I'm not sure why `names` will not work, but if it the `.names` you can replace it with `['names']` like this; `list(df['names'].index[mask])`.

Comment: That's my fault that I used another index name in the real problem and now I understood your point. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To select a row or group of rows fulfilling a condition, you can use this:

```
subSelection=df[df["names"].str.contains("ccdd")]
```

To print the rows, use can use `print(subSelection)` and to print the indices of the selected rows, you can use `print(list(subSelection.index))`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
I tried the code you leave and get an error "Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values". It might be because of 2 Nans in mask array. So I added the `na=False` option from the first reply. That give me a row values. I fill I can check the elements in that row and get the value.